# Pagination Query for MS Access

Tags: php, sql, ms-access

Does MS Access support pagination query like in MySQL

I have tried the SQL query below

```
//MySQL working sample
$SQLi = "SELECT * FROM orders WHERE orders.qty > '1' ORDER BY orders.id ASC LIMIT 0,25";

//the query below gets only top 20 on MS Access with no OFFSET
$SQLi_2 = "SELECT TOP 20 orders.qty FROM orders WHERE orders.qty > '1' ORDER BY orders.id ASC";

//the query below works only on SQL-Server but failed to work MS Access
//I want something like this to work on MS Access
$SQLi_3 = "SELECT * FROM orders WHERE orders.qty > '1' ORDER BY orders.id ASC OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 20 ROWS ONLY";
```

Any help would be appreciate

Comment: AFAIK Access does not support this. I really wouldn't use Access as the backend for a PHP web app though anyway...use SQL Server Express, mySQL, SQLite even...but not Access. It's just not designed for it.

Comment: I had to do array pagination, since it is not more 2000 records.
Someone should tell Microsoft to adopt MySQL Engine for MS Access and Chrome/Mozilla Firefox Engine for IE/Edge
Lol

Comment: Actually they will soon be using the Chrome engine for Edge , you might have seen it if you read technology news. As for Access, it's good at what it does and doesn't need changing. But it's not really an appropriate choice of technology for your application